# Spring boot 2.4.2 doesn't work properly in ResponseEntity return with 409(conflict)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

When am returning conflict in spring boot 2.4.2 with below line, Response show it as 204 instead of conflict.

```
 return new ResponseEntity<>(httpHeaders, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
```

Is it the bug in spring boot 2.4.2 or am i missing something ? Please guide me on this.

Comment: It's impossible for me to tell why the status isn't 409 based on a return statement alone. Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: There is no problem with the **version (2.4.2)**, it works correctly. We need to see your code.

Comment: Thanks for the update. it was another issue with my project dependency jars where they overridden this response code. Found and addressed it. Thanks